# Resnet Implementation CNN

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, resnet

I am compressing and decompressing an image using CNN and have used the Fashion MNIST dataset. After 3 epochs, the accuracy I am getting is 67%. How can I use Resnet in my encoder and decoder? The libraries I have added are :

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Flatten, MaxPool2D, BatchNormalization, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator, load_img
from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import image
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

The following are the functions for encoder and decoder -

```
def EncoderCNN(image_shape, encode_len, layers):
  layers = helper_layers(image_shape, layers)

  encoder_input = keras.Input(shape=image_shape, name="EncoderInput")

  x = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
  x = custom_layers.CNNBlock(layers[0][0], True, layers[0][1])(encoder_input)

  for layer in layers[1:]:
    x = custom_layers.CNNBlock(layer[0], True, layer[1])(x)

  x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
  encoder_output = keras.layers.Dense(encode_len, activation="relu", name="EncoderOutput")(x)
  return keras.Model(encoder_input, encoder_output, name='EncoderCNN')


def DecoderCNN(image_shape, encode_len, layers):
    helper_shape = layers[0][2]
    decoder_input = keras.Input(shape=(encode_len,), name="DecoderInput")

    x = ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
    x = keras.layers.Dense(utils.number_of_pixels(helper_shape), activation="relu")(decoder_input)

    x = keras.layers.Reshape(helper_shape)(x)

    for layer in layers:
        x = custom_layers.CNNBlock(layer[0], False, layer[1])(x)

    decoder_output = keras.layers.Conv2D(image_shape[2], 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
    return keras.Model(decoder_input, decoder_output, name='DecoderCNN')
```

Have I correctly used

> x = ResNet50(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')

As of now, using Resnet50 has not improved my accuracy.
How can I use Resnet101?